# Unreal Engine replication on two PCs

Tags: networking, unreal-engine5

I've been learning Unreal Engine's Networking Lately, So, I've managed to make characters spawn in the same room in the editor:
[image: Editor Image]

However, When i build the game and run it twice (either from the same PC, or from two different PCs) each of them spawns in its own room:

[image: Two Builds]
So what should i do to fix it, Thanks.

Expected that the two players join the same world in the build.

Comment: One of the instances must work "as a server" and the other must be "a client", where during connection you will provide it information to "connect to the server".